# Ingest pipeline with update_by_query on failure causes version_conflict_engine_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

**Situation**:
I set the "[on_failure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html#handling-pipeline-failures)" statement to an existing pipeline like follows (for the whole pipeline):

```
"on_failure" : [
  {
    "set" : {
      "field" : "_index",
      "value" : "failed-{{ _index }}"
    }
  },
  {
    "set" : {
      "field" : "caused_by",
      "value" : "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
    }
  }
]
```

**Problem**:
The pipeline is used with the update_by_query API to enrich documents. In case of a failure, the pipeline does not forward the failed document to the failed index ie. failed-my_index. This results due to the following error message:

```
{
  "took": 276,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 1,
  "updated": 0,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 1,
  "version_conflicts": 1,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": [
    {
      "index": "failed-my_index",
      "type": "_doc",
      "id": "1002109",
      "cause": {
        "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason": "[1002109]: version conflict, required seqNo [37265539], primary term [20]. but no document was found",
        "index_uuid": "JMepgCegQamU8WDqQuFJ3Q",
        "shard": "0",
        "index": "failed-my_index"
      },
      "status": 409
    }
  ]
}
```

This is true, because the document "1002109" doesn't exist in the failed index, because it didn't fail when it was indexed originally. **On update, the pipeline fails, and the document needs to go into the failed index. This is not happening because of the version conflict error above.**

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-source) about the `_update_by_query` endpoint:

> This API only enables you to modify the source of matching documents, **you cannot move them.**

This information is also available in the scripting documentation regarding what can be done in [the update by query context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.12/painless-update-by-query-context.html) as we can see that most of the `ctx._*` fields are read-only:

> - ctx['_routing'] (String, **read-only**) : The value used to select a shard for document storage.
> - ctx['_index'] (String, **read-only**): The name of the index.
> - ctx['_type'] (String, **read-only**): The type of document within an index.
> - ctx['_id'] (int, **read-only**): The unique document id.
> - ctx['_version'] (int, **read-only**): The current version of the
>   document.

So, it's not possible to change the index of a document using update by query. You can, however, flag the documents and then use a combination of reindex + delete-by-query to move those flagged documents to your failed index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If this is true, then it must be a bug, because the normal specs for ingest pipeline permit this for handling pipeline failures when its running ...

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature, I've updated my answer